# How to use blade @include in laravel4-theme

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm use the [laravel4-theme](https://github.com/teepluss/laravel4-theme) and I have to try use @include, but always says that view does not exist, but she exists.

```
@include('groups/partials/table')
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel automatically adds the `.blade.php` for you

so just use

```
@include('groups/partitals/table')
```

Comment: sorry, poorly scanned the question. in my code was no longer writing writing the extension. I've edited the question.

Comment: Your file is in the `app/views/groups/partitals/` directory?

Comment: no. laravel4-theme use a diferent struct. my view is in the directory ```public/themes/mythemes/views/groups/partials```

Comment: Then double check your spelling: `partitals` !== `partials`

Comment: But you may also want to consider using `echo Theme::partial('groups/partitals/table');`